# Sharing data connections between EXCEL and PowerBI

Tags: excel, powerbi

I have an old EXCEL file which has a direct connection to a sharepoint list. I want to use that exact connection and it's parameters in PowerBI.

I have tried exporting an ODC file but cannot load it in PowerBi.
Is that `command text` from the connection proprieties of any use?

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the PowerQuery Editor in Excel
2. Copy all the queries with crtl-c
3. Open the PowerQuery Editor in Power BI
4. Paste all the queries with ctrl-v

Comment: Didn't work for you? Why?

Comment: Hello @Peter, thanks for your response.
I don't have any queries, I only have connections to sharepoint lists. The query panel inside PowerQuery is empty - nothing to copy